# Joomla module for switching templates

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions

In Joomla 2.5 / 3.2 is there any module for switching template parts or templates?
Here is what I need. I have main website like: `http://www.example.com/` 
and I need to add parameter like partner name so it will be `http://www.example.com/partner-name/` with changed Logo and some color changes, but everything else would be the same.

Comment: Here's a little clue to get you started off: http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_determine_if_the_user_is_viewing_the_front_page

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is **"Assigning more than one template for the Front-end"** 
http://docs.joomla.org/J3.2:Switching_templates#Assigning_more_than_one_template_for_the_Front-end